# How to assign existing NIC/Vnet to VM on Azure portal while creating a VM?

Tags: azure, azureportal

When creating a VM, as we can see in the image below, we cannot choose an existing VNet. The solution I found is to create using ARM template and specify an existing VM. More over it is stated "When creating a virtual machine, a network interface will be `created for you`."

1. Is there a better way to do this on portal? (even though it is a combo box, we really cannot select an existing vnet)
2. Why is Azure not allowing it when the same functionality is available for storage accounts (choosing existing network)?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK it is possible. your screenshot show you can select existing Vnet.. The VM is in the same region >?

Comment: Not it is not, I edited the question to mention it. I had a vnet in the same region and RG.

Comment: more over it is stated "When creating a virtual machine, a network interface will be created for you."

Comment: are we talking about nic or vnet here ?

Comment: Vnet. wish Nic was there too as an option

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot select the existing NIC in the way you used as the screenshot shows, but you can select the existing Vnet in the same region. As you see, Azure will create the nic itself for you.

In the Azure portal, you can only use the template to create a VM with both existing NIC and Vnet as I know. And you can also achieve what you want using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create) locally. Also does the PowerShell and REST API and etc.